# Automating the processes in "Active Directory Users and Computers"

Tags: python, powershell, active-directory

I am looking for a solution to automate the windows **"Active Directory Users and Computers"**. I want to automate two processes

- Account Unlock
- Password Reset

The flow that I have envisioned is that:

1. Users raise tickets for Account Unlock/password reset on a ticketing tool (Redmine)
2. The details are passed to the administrator's system
3. The system launches the "Active Directory Users and Computers"
4. The "Find Users" window will be opened by Action -> Find
5. The user name would be typed in and the find now button will be clicked
6. In the Search results, the user detail properties will be opened
7. The process will move to the relevant tab and unlock the account/reset the password

For steps 1 and 2 we plan to use python/shell script with ssh commands
For the steps 3 till 7 is where we are unable to decide which script/tool to use to automate the process.

I looked in the web and saw a few options

- powershell
- python
- AD Manager Plus

I prefer to automate using open source tools.

Could you please suggest the better alternative to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Having said that, I will note that my organization has a PowerShell script that, given a user's sAMAccountName, will determine whether it's locked in Active Directory, and will unlock it. No interaction with the GUI is needed; look at the PowerShell Active Directory module that's installed when you install RSAT.

Comment: I was finally able to get the commands running through powershell script called through a bat file. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read about [Active Directory Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx).

There is no need to open a GUI and click buttons, you can do the same actions through PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you.I was finally able to get the commands running through powershell script called through a bat file. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

A guide on where to download RSAT, how to turn RSAT on, and used within powershell can be located here:

https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/

Comment: I was finally able to get the commands running through powershell script called through a bat file. Thanks for the assist.